# How to set up basic WCF service - client application?

Tags: wcf, service, reference, client, msdn

I am new to WCF and I try to create my first WCF service - client application. I use Visual Studio 2010.

1. I create WCF Service application
2. I try to add service reference to my another project. After pressing "discover", the service occured. After clicking on it or expanding, an error occurs. I tried to fix the config files, but the error messages were just changing.

What is the minimum configuration to keep the basic WCF service working?

Comment: Please do post what errors are encountered?

Answer (score -1):

Server Side configuration

```
 <services>
  <service name="Program01.TestClass" behaviorConfiguration="testBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"   
     contract="Contracts.IContract"/>
     <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9817/TestService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="testBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Client side configuration

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:9817/TestService" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
   name="ClientEndPoint"
   contract="Contracts.IContract"/>
</client>
```

Use ChannelFactory to obtain proxy and invoke the method. cheers :)-

Comment: -1: why would you think that _your_ configuration will help the OP?